# Show corresponding <div> when clicking on link

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

Link a is surrounded by `foreach` and the div elements are also surrounded by `foreach`.

I want, when we click on a link `<a>` the corresponding `<div>` content appears and when you click on another link, the corresponding `<div>` content appears replacing the previously displayed content.

Link to:

```
@foreach($ projects as $ project)
<a onclick="myFunction('project'+$project-> id}}) ">
 Click
</a>
@endforeach
```

The div content:

```
@foreach($ projects as $ project)
<div id="project {{$ project-> id}}" style="display: none">
  Content {{ $ project-> id}}
</div>
@endforeach
```

Here is the JavaScript function I am using:

```
<script>
  function myFunction (x) {
          if (document.getElementById (x) .style.display == "none") {
    document.getElementById(x).style.display = "flex";
          } else {
    document.getElementById(x).style.display = "none";
          }
       }
</script>
```

Comment: What is your problem with the current code?

Comment: change `id="project {{$ project-> id}}"` to `id="project{{$ project-> id}}"`. I have removed space between `project` and brackets

Comment: There is a space in the `<div>` id. An id can't have spaces in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In blade file

```
 @foreach($projects as $project)
    <a href="#"  class="projectLink" data-id="{{$project->id}}">
     Click
    </a>
    @endforeach
```

and for div

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
<div id="project-{{$project->id}}" class="project" style="display: none">
  Content {{ $project->id}}
</div>
@endforeach
```

Then in script

```
<script>
$(document).on('click','.projectLink',function(){
   $('.project').hide();
  var activeProject=$(this).attr("data-id");
  $('#project-'+activeProject).show();
})
</script>
```

Comment: Hello Mr@John Lolo. Thank you very much, your help met all my expectations, again a big thank you.